# Install tensorflow version 0.12

Tags: tensorflow, pip, installation

How can i install the tensorflow 0.12 on windows x64 CPU.

If it is nowhere to be found

I tried to install through pip for python 3.6. Did not work out

```
pip install --user install tensorflow==0.12
```

Also tried this command with python 3.5, but nothing happened either

Comment: What output do you get when running `py -3.6 -c "from setuptools import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_supported()[0])"` from command line?

Comment: Are you sure you want version *0.12* and not **1.12.0**? Version *0.12* was release in 2016 while **1.12.0** is the current release.

Comment: @hoefling , C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\pep425tags.py:89: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
  warn=(impl == 'cp')):
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\pep425tags.py:93: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
  warn=(impl == 'cp')):
('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win_amd64')

Comment: @phd, I need specifically 0.12

Answer (score 5):

[tensorflow 0.12.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/0.12.0/#files) was only released for Python 3.5, not 3.6

[tensorflow 0.12.1](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/0.12.1/#files) was released for Python 3.6 but only on Linux and MacOS.

If you instist on installing version 0.12 your best bet is to try tensorflow 0.12.1 installed for Python 3.5:

```
py -3.5 -m pip install tensorflow==0.12.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The only version 0.X available on pypi is the 0.12.1 for python 3.6, hence you can run

```
pip install tensorflow==0.12.1
```

Comment: Collecting tensorflow==0.12.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==0.12.1 (from versions: 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.13.0rc0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==0.12.1

Comment: Are you sure you're using python3.6? Because I can install 0.12.1 without any problem running the command above. Btw, it resolves to the following url https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/a5/45b172f20e2fabd19c7f18a44570fc82acc4c628ec9bc4b313de39c4fe37/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl maybe you try `pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/a5/45b172f20e2fabd19c7f18a44570fc82acc4c628ec9bc4b313de39c4fe37/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

Comment: If install from file:  tensorflow-0.12.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Uh I'm sorry - I just read you're using Windows - of course, you can't install that wheel since is built for Linux. You can try to run python 3.5 and install the prebuilt windows wheel with `pip install https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/raw/master/0.12.0/py35/CPU/avx/tensorflow-0.12.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: It does not matter, I tried to install it this way. Always writes the same

Comment: That's weird, it's a wheel built for windows x64 + python 3.5 - it should work

Answer (score 0):

Although the thread is about windows system but sharing it for the ubuntu users as well. That's how I downloaded it in my ubuntu 1804 system after following the comment of @phd,

1. created a conda enviornment using python 3.5
   `conda create -n tf012 python=3.5`
2. and then installed TF 0.12 with `pip install tensorflow==0.12`