# Getting error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, magenta, google-music

I am trying to install ai duet in Windows 10, I already installed all the requirements (TensorFlow, Magenta, Flask, Gunicorn and iPython), I am doing python server.py but don't work.

I was already looking at solutions on the internet but they do not work, I have the problem in events_rnn_graph.py since contrib is used many times.
It's for a college assignment.

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\magenta\aiexperiments-ai-duet\server>python server.py
2020-05-27 01:47:20.875736: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-05-27 01:47:20.879432: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 17, in <module>
    from predict import generate_midi
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\magenta\aiexperiments-ai-duet\server\predict.py", line 20, in <module>
    from magenta.models.melody_rnn import melody_rnn_config_flags
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\magenta\models\melody_rnn\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from magenta.models.shared import events_rnn_model
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\magenta\models\shared\events_rnn_model.py", line 28, in <module>
    from magenta.models.shared import events_rnn_graph
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\magenta\models\shared\events_rnn_graph.py", line 31, in <module>
    base_cell=tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\magenta\aiexperiments-ai-duet\server>
```

I am finding it very difficult to install piano duet

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: Quite a lot [of potential duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=AttributeError%3a%20module%20%27tensorflow%27%20has%20no%20attribute%20%27contrib%27&mixed=0) here.

Comment: im using the last tensorflow version

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow 2.0 seems not having `contrib` attribute. make sure you install the same version as the repo specified (0.12.1 I think? according to [here](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/aiexperiments-ai-duet/blob/master/server/requirements.txt#L1))

Comment: i already try that but give me this error, and 0.12.1 also dont work
C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\magenta\aiexperiments-ai-duet>pip install tensorflow==1.15
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15

Comment: which python version you are using? according to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386222/install-tensorflow-version-0-12), 0.12.1 only works for python3.5;