# Is there any way I could install Tensorflow 0.12.1 in my windows maching with windows 10 OS?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to run a piece of code which works only with Tensorflow 0.12.1. When I tried to install the particular version using this command `py -3.5 -m pip install tensorflow==0.12.1`, I am getting this error

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==0.12.1 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==0.12.1

I have Python 3.5 and 3.6 installed in my machine.

If I try installing using `pip install tensorflow==0.12.1`, I am getting this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==0.12.1 (from versions: 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0rc0, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==0.12.1
```

this is the piece of code i am trying to run

```
# Create placeholders
features_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, feature_size], 'features')
stances_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None], 'stances')
keep_prob_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Infer batch size
batch_size = tf.shape(features_pl)[0]

# Define multi-layer perceptron
hidden_layer = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(tf.contrib.layers.linear(features_pl, hidden_size)), keep_prob=keep_prob_pl)
logits_flat = tf.nn.dropout(tf.contrib.layers.linear(hidden_layer, target_size), keep_prob=keep_prob_pl)
logits = tf.reshape(logits_flat, [batch_size, target_size])

# Define L2 loss
tf_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
l2_loss = tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in tf_vars if 'bias' not in v.name]) * l2_alpha

# Define overall loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, stances_pl) + l2_loss)

# Define prediction
softmaxed_logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
predict = tf.arg_max(softmaxed_logits, 1)
sess = tf.Session()
util.load_model(sess)
return sess, keep_prob_pl, predict, features_pl, bow_vectorizer, tfreq_vectorizer, tfidf_vectorizer
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403749/12396281) comment
It says that is impossible

Answer (score 1):

I am able to install tensorflow==0.12.1 on Python==3.5.2 on Windoes 10. Actually this configuration combination is recommended in one of the github [project](https://github.com/uclnlp/fakenewschallenge)